# Executing variable code in Groovyshell

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

Consider this piece of code

```
 def RespJson = RespSlurper.parseText(content)    
 def RespNode= "RespJson"+"."+ assertionKey
```

where `assertionKey` will change dynamically on each iteration and will be having values like `seatbid[0].bid[0].impid`

How can I execute the below code in Groovyshell, I am trying this

```
def v    
def a = new Binding(RespJson: RespJson)
new GroovyShell(a).evaluate(" v=${RespNode}")
log.info(v)
```

But I got the value of v as `null` . Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
def RespSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def content = step.testRequest.response.responseContent
```

and the value of `content` is

```
{  
   "seatbid":[  
      {  
         "bid":[  
            {  
               "id":"1",
               "impid":"1",
               "price":3.5999999046325684,
               "nurl":"http:...",
               "adomain":[  
                  "zagg.com",
                  "zagg.com"
               ],
               "iurl":"http:...",
               "crid":"30364.s320x50m",
               "h":0,
               "w":0
            }
         ],
         "group":0
      }
   ],
   "cur":"USD",
   "nbr":0
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that can be tested in groovyshell? There are unknown pieces to this (such as `RespSlurper`, `content`). Thanks.

Comment: as an alternative, to just the the return value, there would be `def data=[a:[1,2,3]]; assert 3==Eval.x(data, "x.a[2]")`.  yet i think, that the path `RespNode` just yields `null` as result.

Comment: @mnd  Thanks for your reply.  I edited the question with responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the code below as what I think is a condensed version of what the question is asking.

In this case it seems that the `v` variable can be retrieved off of the binding, which is `a`. The binding has its variables available on a `variables` object.

Also, because the script evaluated by the GroovyShell is the same as what `v` is set to, printing the output of the GroovyShell object will also print "1".

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def RespSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def content = '{"seatbid":[{"bid":[{"id":"1","impid":"1","price":3.5999999046325684,"nurl":"http:...","adomain":["zagg.com","zagg.com"],"iurl":"http:...","crid":"30364.s320x50m","h":0,"w":0}],"group":0}],"cur":"USD","nbr":0}'
def RespJson = RespSlurper.parseText(content)
def assertionKey = "seatbid[0].bid[0].impid"
def RespNode= "RespJson"+"."+ assertionKey
def v
def a = new Binding(RespJson: RespJson)
def result = new GroovyShell(a).evaluate("v=${RespNode}")
println(v)
// Important addition!
println(result)         <=== print the value of the GroovyShell, it will show "1"
println(a.variables.v)  <=== retrieve the "v" variable off of the binding, it will show "1"
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Didnt realized that the correct result is in the `result` . Additionally I learned how to work with `variables` object. in `Groovyshell` .